# How to run a while loop?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to make a forms application that update the text in a `textBox` every 0.1 sec
so I did that:

```
private void Start_Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    double x;
    while (true)
    {
        x = x + 0.00522222222222222222222222222222;
        y.Text = x.ToString();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

but when I ran the program, it just froze
(I wrote almost the exact program in a console application and it ran smoothly).

Comment: execute the method in another thread or use `Timer`

Comment: i tryed using another thread but it gave me some other errors, but how can i use a timer??

Comment: @ronald7894 it's not only about using other thread but you should be able to invoke changes on your UI thread from that thread. One of possible solutions here is to use synchronization context. It is explained in my answer...

Comment: @ronald7894 Yuval already posted a working answer...

Comment: Check my updated answer. it supports start and stop in the same button!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not making much sense, You can achieve what you want using [`Task.Delay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx). It will asynchronously yield control back to the UI message loop (internally, it uses a timer):

```
private bool shouldIterate;
private async void StartStopClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (shouldIterate)
    {
        shouldIterate = false;
        return;
    }

    shouldIterate = true;
    while (shouldIterate)
    {
        x = x + 0.00522222222222222222222222222222;
        y.Text = x.ToString();
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

Although I suggest you set your interval to something more reasonable.

Comment: tnx man it's working, and i have another question, how on another click on that button can i break that loop??

Comment: In this solution i have to make another button, is there a possibility to do it without an additional button??

Comment: @ronald How would you want to cancel it? After a certain time interval?

Comment: i would like to make a single button that can start on stops the while loop

Comment: @ronald don't change your question once you got an answer (also not through comments). Try to research each separate problem yourself and ask a new question if you can't figure it out.

Comment: This is a very good solution. Although i'd suggest to use keyword volatile here....

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Well this is not entirely true... By adding keyword async it enables the method to be split into multiple pieces, some of which run asynchronously...

Comment: @Fabjan What multiple pieces are you talking about?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
double x = 0;
Timer timer1 = new Timer();

public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     timer1.Interval = 100;
     timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
}

private void Start_Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (timer1.Enabled)
     {
         timer1.Stop();
     }
     else
     {
         timer1.Start();
     }
}
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     x = x + 0.00522222222222222222222222222222;
     textBox1.Text = x.ToString();
}
```

Comment: @OldFox Accepted answer did not initially answer on that either. It's simple to apply logic with bool flag and timer start/stop here aswell. This is just answer that is easier to understand for a beginner. I clearly doubt he understood the part with async await in the answer that he accepted.

Comment: @msmolcic I agree with you, YuvalItzchakov didn't explain his answer and I didn't like it. Take a look in the question's comments I wrote to the OP to use `Timer`, my computer is not windows, I understood that the OP is a beginner and I didn't want to confuse him with typos...  user2946329 `Timer` has property named: `Enabled`, you don't need to add any additional field. Update your answer then I'll vote up....

Answer (score 0):

You can also run a separate task passing it a synchronization context. Use volatile keyword to make sure that your isCanceled field can be used in a thread-safe way from different thread. You can use it as condition for your 'while' loop (to start/stop your task).

```
   volatile bool isCanceled = true;

   private void Start_Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {            
        isCanceled = !isCanceled;
        if(isCanceled) return;

        // gets context of current UI thread (to update smth later using it)
        SynchronizationContext cont = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        // starts hot task with your logic
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {                                
             double x = 0;
             while (!isCanceled )
             {
                x = x + 0.05;

                // this operation will be executed on UI thread with use of sync context
                cont.Post(delegate { y.Text = x.ToString(); }, null);                

                Thread.Sleep(100);
             }
        });
    }
```